# Updating PyCharm running with Flatpak

Tags: pycharm, flatpak

I am running a computer with Linux Mint 19. I installed PyCharm Community Edition using LM's software centre.

Now, there is an update for PyCharm but I cannot install it. 
When I do Help > Check for updates, the window that opens says "PyCharm does not have write access to /app/pycharm. Please run it by a privileged user to update."

So I thought that I had to run PyCharm in sudo to be able to apply the update.

Problem : there is no /app folder on this computer. Neither is there a pycharm file in /usr/bin or /opt or whatever (I ran a full OS search of pycharm.sh).

When I check in LM's menu editor the command that is run when launching PyCharm, it is :

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=pycharm-desktop com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community
```

I tried the same line with a sudo but that did not seem to work (PyCharm does not launch).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.
I just found how to it works base [on this help page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206601265-Fixed-PyCharm-automatic-update-fails-on-Linux-due-to-permissions).

The *sudo locate pycharm.sh* did find the pycharm.sh file (when Nemo had not). I did use the command listed, i.e. :

```
sudo updatedb && sudo locate pycharm.sh
sudo /path/to/pycharm.sh
```

It created a root PyCharm profile and then I could update PyCharm using Help > Check for updates.